# Prophet fit() does not recognize dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run a Prophet time series model on a standard pandas dataframe.  First column is a date datatype.  I made sure the second column is a float.  However, I keep getting told that the argument needs to be a dataframe.  It is a dataframe and a dataframe in the format that Prophet us supposed to be.  Any ideas why I am getting: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'?

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
from fbprophet.plot import add_changepoints_to_plot

df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//initialClaims.csv", header=None, encoding='utf-8' )
df[1] = df[1].astype(float)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
ds = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
y = df[1].astype(float)

# Fit prophet model
m = Prophet
m.fit(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `m = Prophet` with `m = Prophet()` as per the documentation and see if that helps